# How to parse string between brackets and store in key value?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

How to parse the below string inside brackets and store name, desc and id in array using php?

## Format 1

```
NAME1 DESC1
{
10000
}

NAME2 DESC2
{
20000
}
```

## Format 2

```
// also remove comments
// c++ file.inc
NAME1 DESC1{1000}NAME2 DESC2{2000}
```

I tried the below code, but I only get the ID

```
$inc = file_get_contents($inc_path);
$inc = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$inc);
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $inc, $matches);

// results
[0]=> string(5) "10000" 
[1]=> string(5) "20000"
```

My expected results are:

```
[0]=> array(3) {[0] => "NAME1", [1] => "DESC1", [3] => "10000"} 
[1]=> array(3) {[0] => "NAME2", [1] => "DESC2", [3] => "20000"}
```

Comment: Is that text inside a single variable? Can there be more than one NAME or DESC or 10000?

Comment: No, it is a file content. I also want to parse and remove comments also parse using the format 2

Comment: This is the actual code after testing your code. https://ideone.com/THVwh5

Comment: So, you need https://ideone.com/EJrNKe ?

Comment: yes, it's working when I hard code the string but when I read the contents using file_get_contents it removes the new line. So the result is become empty

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression and code, using the `m` modifier and `^` anchor:

```
$re = '/(^\w+)\s+(0x[a-f\d]+)\s+\{\s+(\w+)/m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$res = array_map(function ($match) { return array_slice($match, 1); }, $matches);
```

See it run on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/lui5v6)

Comment: yes, it's working when I hard code the string but when I read the contents using file_get_contents it removes the new line. So the result is become empty

Comment: `file_get_contents` does not remove new lines. Are you sure you did not remove them yourself with  `$inc = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$inc);`? That you should of course not do.

Comment: this is the actual code https://ideone.com/JJy2UE, there is no preg_replace. Try to save the content to sample.inc and the result will be empty.

Comment: Updated code https://ideone.com/Nq2XEZ and actual inc file [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ronjunelopez/70e98d89f3a127dc8ca035a5e96cb4b8/raw/0b5e00c99d7a0c887ed8068e64cada95fc8aa117/sample.inc)

Comment: Try with unicode modifier in the regular expression: `/mu` instead of `/m`.